# An optimisation problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have an optimisation probem given below

$$argmax_{x_i \ \ \forall x_i=1,2...n} \sum_{i} S_ie^{-\alpha x_i}$$

subject to

$$\sum x_i = 1$$
$$\sum C_i x_i \leq B $$ 
$$\forall i \ \  x_i \geq 0 $$ 
where $\alpha >1$ , $B >0$ and $  \forall i \ \ C_{i}>0,S_{i} >0 $   are constants.

I have to calculate a solution for this problem computationally, given all the constants $\alpha,B,    C_{i},S_{i} \ \ \forall i$ . I tried Lagrange multipliers method , but I am not able to get a closed solution, but i do have the a set of linear equations . Is there a way to solve this problem computationally ?

Comment: First of all you can drop the third constraint If $\sum x_i=1$ then obviously $\sum x_i\geq 0$. Or do you have made a typo somewhere ? If yes, then please make an edit.

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks callculus